# Execute command from a file each second

Tags: bash, macos, curl

I have a file with a bunch of different curl commands. For example, curls.txt:

```
curl http:/localhost:7070/a
curl http:/localhost:7070/b
curl http:/localhost:7070/c
curl http:/localhost:7070/d
curl http:/localhost:7070/e
curl http:/localhost:7070/f
curl http:/localhost:7070/g
```

How can I run each command from this file but with a 1 second delay?

Comment: Sure, add `sleep 1` after each line.

Comment: what's the point? what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do like this in bash:

```
while read cmd; do echo "$cmd" ; $cmd ; sleep 1 ; done < curls.txt
```

Comment: its executing every 1 seconds but throws errors :c I tried each one of your pre edited answers too :D

`curl http://localhost:7070/a
zsh: no such file or directory: curl http://localhost:7070/a
curl http://localhost:7070/b
zsh: no such file or directory: curl http://localhost:7070/b
curl http://localhost:7070/c
zsh: no such file or directory: curl http://localhost:7070/c`

Comment: Did you try to execute it with the quotes around it? That won't work...

Comment: It seems to work only in Bash (not Zsh).
It should be without the quotes around $cmd or the curl arguments will not be understood correcly

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason they had to be in a file?

```
for x in a b c d e f g
do curl http:/localhost:7070/$x; sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score -1):

As Mark said I've added sleep 1 after each line and execute a file with: bash curls.txt.  Works like a charm. Thanks :)